# Array of pointer

Tags: c

please help to fixed this program.
I'm try to print array of pointer using pointer instead of array but i got this error:

```
pointer_multi_char4.c: In function ‘main’:
pointer_multi_char4.c:7:11: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
char **message;
message= { "Four", "score", "and", "seven",
               "years", "ago,", "our", "forefathers" };
printf("%s\n",message);
return 0;
}
```

how can i fixed this code?
please somebody explain me what's wrong with that code

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't just want to be using a char* to the string "Four score and seven years ago our forefathers"?

Comment: `char**` != `char*[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    char **message;
    message= (char* []){ "Four", "score", "and", "seven",
               "years", "ago,", "our", "forefathers" };
    int numOfMessage = 8;
    while(numOfMessage--){
        printf("%s\n", *message++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    char *message[] =  { "Four", "score", "and", "seven",
                         "years", "ago,", "our", "forefathers", 0 };

    int loop;
    for (loop = 0; message[loop]; ++loop) printf("%s\n",message[loop]);
    return 0;
}
```

The braces in this case (making an assumption) is that you want to initialise an array (hence the use of `char *message[]` instead of `char **`.

As it is an array need to loop over it. I used a null pointer to mark the end of the array

**EDIT**

Then @Lundu just need

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char * mesage="Four scor and seven years .... forefathers";
    printf("%s\n", message);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is worth mentioning, that in @EdHeal example the **initialization** is in the same line as declaration. If you make it as two separate instructions, it's no longer an initialization - it's an **assignment**.

Comment: I'm tryng to print this message using pointer instead of array,

Comment: @Smac89 - More speed less haste